# Problem with QGIS plugin SMART MAP

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am having problem using the QGIS plugin called SMART MAP. I added a screenshot. As you can see I does not allow me to maximize the tab, making it impossible to work on since all the parameters overlap with each other.

QGIS version 3.28, PLUGIN (smart map) version 1.3.3

Things I already tried:

- downloading version 1.3.2 and 1.3.1 of smart map
- downloading version 3.24 of QGIS and installing the versions 1.3.3,
  1.3.2 and 1.3.1.
- making sure versions are compatible

Has anyone had this problem or an idea on how to fix it?

[image]